# .htaccess rewriterule not working for single page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a couple pages:

```
http://waleyqiao.com/about/
http://waleyqiao.com/index/
http://waleyqiao.com/contact/
http://waleyqiao.com/blog/
http://waleyqiao.com/portfolio/
```

The real pages would be waleyqiao.com/about.html

**htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

For some reason, waleyqiao.com/portfolio/ does not seem to work but waleyqiao.com/portfolio.html does...

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are tacking the `.html` right on the end of the URI:

```
/portfolio/.html
```

which obviously doesn't exist. You need to create a grouping without the trailing slash. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html
```

And likewise for the php extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) /%1.php [L]
```